# how to make javascript popup unblocked in any browser without user interference?

Tags: javascript, popup, popup-blocker

I have used popup at many places in my website (its in PHP with Mysql DB and lots of javascript). These are mostly been blocked my browsers, which restricts user to move ahead. what should do in my code so that my popups becomes Popyp blocker independent..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Jquery Dialogs http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ they are purely javascript and so popup blockers will not block this

Comment: +1 I like this... But can i use this for form submitting purpose? like wise if this dialog box contains any form which could be processed further?

Comment: yes you can. even add ajax methods for login forms and many other features

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your popups's URL is on the same domain as the main site. Using a link with 'target="_blank"' will never get blocked unless it was manually blocked as the user did the action himself. Switch to alerts and prompts instead of popups.

Comment: What if browsers are by default enabled by pop blocker?, common non techy users are not aware of whats happening behind, how to prompt him in this case?

Comment: If its a link  (<a href....>), then it will work unless the user himself, not the popupblock has blocked your site. This is not the default. If the popupblocker is set to block all popups by default, there is nothing you can do except move to a different system (Like the javascript 'floating divs' in other answers).

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but may be Floating div is a good replacement. Build a js dialog box.